# MySQL multiple update queries vs. one insert … on duplicated key update query

Tags: mysql

I need to update hundreds to thousands rows. I wonder which of the following options is better:

1. sending multiple (hundreds to thousands) "UPDATE" queries
2. sending one (big) "INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" query

More info:

1. The table is InnoDB.
2. The rows are all existing (duplicated). There won't be new rows to be inserted in this operation.
3. About 4 - 10 columns will be involved.
4. Only this one table is involved.
5. I am using PHP to execute the queries.

Insert should be faster because I can batch multiple rows into one single query, but this is a read-heavy table and I am worried about locking. Will the insert query result in more locking problems than the multiple update queries?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show examples of the updates? Why not do it in a single update statement? Or update statements that update batches of rows?

Comment: @ypercube how can you do that?

Comment: Can you show examples of your updates?